# How to left shift by an amount in a register with Xtensa LX7

Tags: assembly, xtensa

What is the correct way to do the following in Xtensa assembly:

a4 = ( 1 << a5 )

where a4 and a5 are registers and a5 could contain the value 0 to 3 (could be 0 to 7 in the future, but not too worried about that now.)

I'm sure this must be simple but it seems to be quite tricky.

Comment: Do you have an optimizing C compiler for that ISA?  I think it's one GCC or clang can target, right? If so, look at its output, for a function that returns that value.  Like https://godbolt.org/z/8Ef5GoxTG from a recently-active ARM question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Xtensa ISA you have to load the shift amount into an internal shift amount register (SAR) using the ssl instruction (set shift left amount). Then you have to use the sll (shift logical left) instruction, which takes two registers, the destination register and the register containing the value to be shifted.  An equivalent to your expression `a4 = ( 1 << a5 )` in assembler is:

```
movi a4, 1
ssl a5
sll a4, a4
```

Comment: There's no special case trick to create a `1<<n` I guess, like an instruction that sets or clears a single bit at a given position?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Good question. The only alternative left shift instruction I see is `slli` (shift left logical immediate) where one can specify the shift amount as a constant, but the value to be shifted must be in a register.  So the opposite situation analogous to `n << const`.